# Neo4j graph algorithm / Node similarity

Tags: neo4j

Suppose this graph down below.

I have a job which requires some skills,  and with this list of skills i am searching for candidates knows the skills (i mean the set of skills required by a specific job).
This is the easy part.

The relationships have an attribute years_of_experience. The correct results requires an where candidate.years_of_experience>= skill.years_of_experience.
I would like to use a procedure like this
`gds.nodeSimilarity`
for having a list of candidates and similarity for each of them.
may i have some help with this query because i tryied but no luck till now

[Graph example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbN1c.jpg)

Example:

```
MATCH aa= (job:JobNode{job_id:'feed85b9-041c-4bb5-b48a-963c9f927e1d'})-[r:REQUIRES]->(s:SkillNode) 
with job 
MATCH bb= (job:JobNode{job_id:'feed85b9-041c-4bb5-b48a-963c9f927e1d'})-[r:REQUIRES]->(s:SkillNode)<-[:KNOWS]-(c:CandidateNode) 
WITH {item:id(job), categories: collect(id(c))} AS userData 
WITH collect(userData) AS data 
CALL gds.alpha.ml.ann.stream({ data: data, algorithm: 'jaccard' }) 
YIELD item1, item2, similarity 
return data
```

Comment: Please also post the query that you tried so far. Thanks.

Comment: MATCH  (job:JobNode{job_id:'feed85b9-041c-4bb5-b48a-963c9f927e1d'})-[r:REQUIRES]->(s:SkillNode) 
OPTIONAL MATCH  (job:JobNode{job_id:'feed85b9-041c-4bb5-b48a-963c9f927e1d'})-[r:REQUIRES]->(ss:SkillNode)<-[k:KNOWS]-(c:CandidateNode) 
return *

This is for the graph in the photo.

now i want to add the procedure gds.nodeSimilarity.

There i have the problem.

Comment: also i have tried another procedure, please have a look in the query.

 MATCH aa= (job:JobNode{job_id:'feed85b9-041c-4bb5-b48a-963c9f927e1d'})-[r:REQUIRES]->(s:SkillNode) with job
 MATCH bb= (job:JobNode{job_id:'feed85b9-041c-4bb5-b48a-963c9f927e1d'})-[r:REQUIRES]->(s:SkillNode)<-[:KNOWS]-(c:CandidateNode)
 WITH {item:id(job), categories: collect(id(c))} AS userData
 WITH collect(userData) AS data
 CALL gds.alpha.ml.ann.stream({
   data: data,
   algorithm: 'jaccard'
 })
 YIELD item1, item2, similarity
 return data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start with the candidates rather than the job. This is because you are comparing the similarities among the candidates based on the skills that the job requires.

```
MATCH (job:JobNode{job_id:'feed85b9-041c-4bb5-b48a-963c9f927e1d'})-[r:REQUIRES]->(s:SkillNode)<-[:KNOWS]-(c:CandidateNode)
MATCH (c)-[:APPLIED_FOR]-(job)
WITH {item:id(c), categories: collect(id(job))} AS userData
WITH collect(userData) AS data
CALL gds.alpha.ml.ann.stream({
   data: data,
   algorithm: 'jaccard'
 })
 YIELD item1, item2, similarity
 return gds.util.asNode(item1).name AS Candidate1, gds.util.asNode(item2).name AS Candidate2, similarity
 ORDER BY Candidate1

 Result:
 ╒════════════╤════════════╤════════════╕
 │"Candidate1"│"Candidate2"│"similarity"│
 ╞════════════╪════════════╪════════════╡
 │"Leo"       │"Manos"     │1.0         │
 ├────────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
 │"Manos"     │"Leo"       │1.0         │
 └────────────┴────────────┴────────────┘
```

EDITED:
I thought the question is about node similarity algorithm in neo4j data science library.  The question is about calculating the percentage of each candidates' skill compared to the total skill required for the job.

Steps:

1. Get the total number of skills required for the job
2. Get all candidates with those skills that the job requires
3. Ensure that this candidate has applied for that job
4. Return the candidate name and his/her skills divided by total skills needed for that job

NOte: the function round(10^2/10^2) is a hack in neo4j. Neo4j is not capable of displaying decimals in desktop. If you want 3 decimal places, use 10^3

```
MATCH (job:JobNode{job_id:'<id>'})-[:REQUIRES]->(sk:SkillNode)
WITH job, count(sk) as total_skills
MATCH (job)-[r:REQUIRES]->(s:SkillNode)<-[k:KNOWS]-(c:CandidateNode)
MATCH (c)-[:APPLIED_FOR]-(job)
WITH c as candidate, count(s) as skills, total_skills
RETURN candidate.name, round(10^2*skills/total_skills)/10^2 as percent

Result:
╒════════════════╤═════════╕
│"candidate.name"│"percent"│
╞════════════════╪═════════╡
│"Leo"           │0.67     │
├────────────────┼─────────┤
│"Manos"         │0.67     │
└────────────────┴─────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

What i am trying is

Leo | job_id | 0.66
Manos | job_id | 0.66

This is because each of them have 2 out of 3 of the required skills.
if someone have 3/3 or 4/4 etc, should return 1
if someone have 1/3, should return 0.33

How should i proceed in order to have this? May i change to other procedure, nodeSimilarity?

Comment: I think you are mixing up the meaning of similarity function and simple percentage calculation. No worries, I will update my answer.

Comment: This is a good question Manos. The answer is a simple arithmetic, the old fashioned way rather than data science. Have a great weekend!

Comment: Many thanks for your answer!
I will add a where closure i need.
Regarding the mixing you said, suppose you are absolutelly right, however i guess that this was what i really need and not the old-fashioned way you suggest!
Really thank you, all the best and have a great weekend too! :)

Comment: @manos if you are satisfied with my answer, upvote it or accept it. thanks.